# Calling a local datasource using KnockoutJs

Tags: html, knockout.js, web-sql

I am wanting to write a small application that holds customers information e.g. contact details and orders.

I am looking at using knockout and need the app to work disconnected to the internet.

My application I am wanting to add a search box (similar to the bootstrap typeahead)at a global level that will allow me to search for a customers and navigate to a view.

The task I am not sure about is using database and using KO vm to read data from the db. I started to look into WebSql to store the customers details and orders, however I can only use webkit which isn't ideal.

Does anyone have any experience in using KO with a local dataset? can anyone suggest any good resources?

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem I ended up writing a small generic abstraction layer modeled around the Repository pattern and writing generic implementations of that pattern for both WebDb and IndexedDB. Supporting WebDB these days is unfortunately necessary due to Apple's ignorance to [support IndexedDB in Safari](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb).